# How to continue with number of guesses after ValueError in guessing game?

Tags: python, loops

I'm going through the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python videos on youtube. I finished the one about random number guessing game and am now adding some stuff to it to make it more complete.

I added some code that makes it so that if you don't enter an integer (which creates a ValueError) the program tells you that you didn't enter an integer. However, the point of the game is that you only get 6 guesses, but when the error comes up it, it resets the number of guesses.

How can I make it so that the error doesn't reset the number of cases?

Here's the code:

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

print ('Hello, what is your name?')
name = input ()

name = name.strip()

print ('Well, ' + name + ' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
secretNumber = random.randint (1, 20)

print ('DEBUG: Secret number is ' + str(secretNumber))

while True: 
    try:
        for guessesTaken in range (1, 7):
            print ('Take a guess.')
            guess  = int (input ())
            
            if guess < secretNumber:
                print ('Your guess is too low.')
            elif guess > secretNumber:
                print ('Your guess is too high.')
            else:
                break # This condition is for the correct guess

        if (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken == 1):
            print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guess.')
            break 
        elif (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken > 1): 
            print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
            break
        else:
            print ('Nope. The number I was thinkig of was ' + str(secretNumber))
            break

    except ValueError:
        print ('You did not enter a number.') # This condition is for if a non-integer is entered.
```

I feel like I've tried every combination of where I can but the try and for loop, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Try writing a function that handles one guess when called. You will probably then find it easier to reason about the rest of the code.

Comment: "I feel like I've tried every combination of where I can but the try and for loop" What happened when you tried putting the `try` completely inside the `for`? What parts of your code do you expect could cause the `ValueError` that is being caught?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `while` loop seems unnecessary because it allows you to try even after 6 attempts.

Therefore the `break` in the last three conditions will also be deleted.

You should put the `try` into the `for` loop so that if an exception is raised, the program will continue to count the number of attempts.

I would do something like:

```
    # This is a guess the number game.
    import random

    print('Hello, what is your name?')
    name = input()

    name = name.strip()

    print('Well, ' + name + ' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
    secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

    print('DEBUG: Secret number is ' + str(secretNumber))

    for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
        try:
            print('Take a guess.')
            guess = int(input())

            if guess < secretNumber:
                print('Your guess is too low.')
            elif guess > secretNumber:
                print('Your guess is too high.')
            else:
                break  # This condition is for the correct guess

        except ValueError:
            print('You did not enter a number.')  # This condition is for if a non-integer is entered.

    if (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken == 1):
        print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guess.')

    elif (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken > 1):
        print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')

    else:
        print('Nope. The number I was thinkig of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

The `except` block also should be moved, to be related to the `try` block, under the block of the loop because we don't want to stop the `for` loop as I mentioned before.

Answer (score -1):

## This is a guess the number game.

import random

print ('Hello, what is your name?')
name = input ()
guess = 0

name = name.strip()

print ('Well, ' + name + ' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
secretNumber = random.randint (1, 20)

print ('DEBUG: Secret number is ' + str(secretNumber))

while True:
for guessesTaken in range (1, 7):
try:
print ('Take a guess.')
guess  = int (input ())

```
        if guess < secretNumber:
            print ('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > secretNumber:
            print ('Your guess is too high.')
        else:
            break # This condition is for the correct guess
    except ValueError:
        print ('You did not enter a number.') # This condition is for if a non-integer is entered.


if (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken == 1):
    print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guess.')
    break 
elif (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken > 1): 
    print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
    break
else:
    print ('Nope. The number I was thinkig of was ' + str(secretNumber))
    break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).